# Can I compile a library from source and install it without breaking whatever needs that library?

Tags: shared-libraries

For example, if I write a program in C that uses zlib, then later want to upgrade zlib for whatever reason, can I just build zlib from source and replace the lib? Or will I have to recompile my original program? Probably depends on static or dynamic linking is my first guess, and I would also guess it would probably work with at least one format.

Comment: haven't done this myself, but I'd imagine you'd need to recreate some symlinks and/or run ldconfig

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a DLL/shared library you wont have to recompile if the new library is backward compatible. Of course, if your application depends on undocumented features, or if the library writers made a mistake, all bets are off.

By backward compatible I mean that the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) is compatible and the behavior of utilized functions is the same.